# ObservableCollection<> list won't update after removing an item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, resharper, observablecollection

I want to remove an item from a `TreeView` to which I bind an `ObservableCollection<TreeNode> TreeViewNode,` of type `TreeNode`. However when I remove an item `TreeViewNodes.Remove(_item);` list doesn not get updated.

I use:

```
public class TreeNode: TreeViewItem
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Show your xaml and collection property.

Comment: Don't delete `ListViewItem`, delete an item in observable collection instead. In MVVM you will typically create a command to delete certain (selected? last? etc.) item and ViewModel will process it by changing observable collection. Then View will update content automatically via binding.

Comment: I delete actually an observable collection item which inherits TreeViewItem. (edited the question) TreeViewNodes.Remove(_item); `_item` is the selected item form the list.

Comment: Your TreeNode class should not be derived from TreeViewItem. It should instead be a pure data item class. The TreeView control will then create a TreeViewItem (an "item container") for each data item instance. Take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: You picked the exact code we didn't need to see in order to answer your question.  We need to see where _item comes from, and how you remove it from the collection.  Which you should have debugged through already to verify you are actually doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: I fixed it.. I have an auto generated treeview heavily nested. I get the node's parent with `UIElement parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child) as UIElement;` than remove it.